Is sober driver job halal or haram?
More context as a sober driver we have to pick the drunk people and drive them home as well as their car. In this job 2 people are required so their must partner so one will drive our own car and other will drive the car of drunk person as well as drunk person.

This question is similar to: Is X halal? (reference question). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Salaam,
In my opinion, of course it is halal to be a driver. I think you are actually doing an act of charity because you are driving them home safely. Maybe, you are even saving their life by getting them to their destination!
Remember that in the Qur'an it states, The Quran verse about saving a life is 5:32, which states, "And whoever saves a life it is as though he had saved the lives of all mankind". Surah Maidah
May Allah (swt) guide you and all to the straight path! Ameen.
Muslim Gap.
